# Flutter Multiple Images upload from gallery

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

How can I upload multiple images from gallery using multipart request
in flutter?
I want to upload multiple image files to the server through the API

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader) for uploading multiple files:

```
final taskId = await uploader.enqueue(
  url: "your upload link", //required: url to upload to
  files: [FileItem(filename: filename, savedDir: savedDir, fieldname:"file")], // required: list of files that you want to upload
  method: UploadMethod.POST, // HTTP method  (POST or PUT or PATCH)
  headers: {"apikey": "api_123456", "userkey": "userkey_123456"},
  data: {"name": "john"}, // any data you want to send in upload request
  showNotification: false, // send local notification (android only) for upload status
  tag: "upload 1"); // unique tag for upload task
);
```